# required field validation only for the first item in a list

Tags: html, angular, ngfor, angular-validation

I am using `Template Driven` for my Angula'rs form and I have a `div` that repeats several times (according to a counter variable).

The thing is , I need the required validation only for the first item in this list and I 'm not sure how to do that.

```html
<div class="form-group required margin-left" *ngFor="let hore of horim;let i = index">
              <label class="control-label translate-label" [id]="'lblShemPratiHore'+i">{{selectedLanguage.shemPrati}}</label>
              <!-- <img src="../../../assets/images/parent.png" alt="shem prati"> -->
              <input 
                [id]="'shemPratiHore'+i" 
                [(ngModel)]="hore.shemPrati" 
                class="form-control input-lg" 
                [name]="'shemPratiHore'+i"
                [attr.aria-describedby]="'lblShemPratiHore'+i" 
                #shemPrati="ngModel" 
                required
                [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"/>/>
                <div *ngIf="shemPrati.errors?.required && shemPrati.touched" class="alert alert-danger">
                  Required Field
                </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try binding to the required attribute if index is equal 0.
[required]="index == 0"

Comment: actually it was very close....please change your answer to : `[required]="i==0"` and I'll accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

The anwer for this post is as follow:
 `[required]="i==0"`